# Proving that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(7,2)} x^2 +y^2-xy=39$ using only the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(7,2)} x^2 +y^2-xy=39$$

So I begin by rewriting the absolute value

$$\mid x^2 + y^2 - xy -39 \mid = \mid (x+7)(x-7) + (y+2)(y-2) - (x-7)(y-2) -2(x-7) -7(y-2)\mid$$

Using the triangle inequality, we have

$$\leq \mid x+7\mid \mid x-7\mid  + \mid y+2\mid \mid y-2\mid  - \mid x-7\mid \mid y-2\mid  -2\mid x-7\mid  -7\mid y-2\mid  \mid$$

Taking $\delta < 1$, we get $\mid x+7 \mid < 15$, $\mid y + 2 \mid < 5$,

$$= 27 \mid x - 7 \mid + 13 \mid y - 2 \mid < 40 \delta$$

So I define $d_{\epsilon} = \min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{40})$.

$\textbf{Did I make a mistake? Is there any simpler way to solve this exercise?}$